# Xcode's iPhone device simulator always prints letter A using AnyDesk

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

As the title says, I am currently using AnyDesk to remotely access a Mac computer, when typing in the simulator of an iphone xcode device, the keyboard prints all letters A, no matter what letter of the alphabet I type, it converts them all to letter A, numbers works perfectly, only for letters of the alphabet, using locally without anydesk this problem does not arise, and it is annoying to have to tap with the mouse on each key of the virtual keyboard of the simulator of an iphone xcode device, I await your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Click the keyboard icon on the top status bar of Anydesk\s window and then select "Auto".

Comment: Hello, I was already in the "auto" mode, I changed it to the "Transfer 1:1" aspect and it worked correctly.

Comment: I changed it to remote and it worked.